# Catch iframe reload with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe loaded dynamically with jQuery like this

```
jQuery('<iframe id="myFrame" src="iframesrc.php"></iframe>').load(function(){
    // do stuff when loaded
}).prependTo("#myDiv");
```

And I want to catch the reload event every time the inner frame is reloaded. I tried this:

```
jQuery('body').on('load', '#myDiv', function() {
    alert('iframe loaded');
});
```

But I'm not getting any response, both on the initial load and when following links inside the iframe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for the `load` action of a div in your example above, not the iframe. Try:

```
$("#myFrame").on("load", function () {
    alert("Hi there, hello");
})
```

Additionally, if you are not using other libraries, use `$()` to access jQuery as opposed to `jQuery()`

Also note that any functions that you want to run on your page must be bound to jQuery's document ready event like so:

```
$(function () {
    // your code goes here
    $("#myFrame").attr("src", "http://google.com"); // <- this works
})

$("#myFrame").attr("src", "http://google.com"); // <- this does not work
```

Comment: Thanks a million!
`jQuery("#myFrame").on("load", function () {
    alert("Hi there, hello");
})`
Worked perfectly. Didn't know that that was a valid way to bind an event because i'm too tired and misread the jQuery documentation ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be sure to click the check box if this best answered your question!

Answer (score -9):

for new url

```
location.assign("http:google.com");
```

The assign() method loads a new document.

reload

```
location.reload();
```

The reload() method is used to reload the current document.